# how do I save a file name so that it includes a varible within the file name?

Tags: python

I have a process that is producing a loss value through a loop. I want to save a file with the lowest loss value as part of the file name.  For example, let's say the lowest loss value is 12.345.  I want the file name to be "C:\some_folder\loss_12345.txt".

thank you for taking the time to explain this to me.

Comment: Just use any form of string formatting. F-string, the `%` operator, or the `.format()` method.

Comment: For python it would be `filename = ` f"loss_{my_var}.txt" ` (in this case, `my_var` would be 12345.)

Comment: Why do you think there's anything special about a filename compared to putting a variable in some other string?

Comment: @Manu The programming language is in the tag

Answer (score 1):

You can try string formatting like the following:

```
lowest_loss_val = 12.345

file_name = f"C:\some_folder\loss_{lowest_loss_val}.txt"
```